# web上へhtmlは表示されたが、cssが反映されない

Tags: css, github-pages

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hideto7007.github.io/portfolio/portfolio_styl.css" type="text/css">
```

と変更しましたが、web上ではcssが反映されていません。どのようにコードを変更すれば反映されますでしょうか？
ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

下記リンク先にコードがあります。
https://github.com/hideto7007/portfolio

Comment: その`href`で指定した場所に該当のファイルをまだアップロードしていないか、あるいは公開する設定(とかあるのでしょうか？)にしていないのでは？ アクセスすると 404 File not found になります。こちらの記事とかが参考になるのでは？ [ポートフォリオをGitHub で公開する](https://qiita.com/0622okakyo/items/e911b6ca26f45d4f5e37), [Github Pagesでポートフォリオを公開する方法](https://saburi.work/2020/08/09/github-pages%E3%81%A7%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%82%92%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/), [Githubで自分のポートフォリオを公開する](https://kurikoa.work/github-pages/), [kazuki19992/portfolio](https://github.com/kazuki19992/portfolio)

Comment: 的確なコメントありがとうございます。下記の絶対パスに変更を行ったところ、問題なく反映されることが出来ました。

Comment: @hideto.tsuzuki さん> もし問題が解決した場合は、[質問を解決済みにして](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/32986)いただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

index.html から見て該当の CSS はサブフォルダにあるので、

```
index.html
│
└ portfolio/portfolio_styl.css
```

参照すべき CSS ファイルの正しい URL は以下になるはずです。

```
https://hideto7007.github.io/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio_styl.css
```

---

リポジトリのデータと GitHub ページで公開した際の対応関係をよく確認してみてください。

- https://github.com/hideto7007/portfolio
- https://hideto7007.github.io/portfolio/

難しいようであれば、まずはサブフォルダを作らずにすべて同じフォルダ内に配置するか、
HTML 内の記述は **相対パス** にしておいた方がよいかもしれません。

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./portfolio/portfolio_styl.css" type="text/css">
```